# replace the string all over buffer emacs

Tags: search, emacs, replace, emacs24

I use `M-x replace-string` or `M-%` to replace strings in emacs buffer.

The problem with them is that they only replace strings in forward from the current position of the buffer. How can i force it all over the buffer ?

I do not want to do `M-<` to reach the start and then do it.

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/q/603185/4542).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible interactively. So let's put up some Elisp together.

```
(defun my-replace-allbuffer (str-orig str-replace)
     (interactive "sString ? \nsReplace with ? ")
     (replace-string str-orig str-replace nil (point-min) (point-max))
     )
```

and bind the function to your prefered key binding.

The documentation of `replace-string` (`C-h f replace-string RET`) tells us it can take the optional arguments start and end of replacement.

More doc:

- http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_basics.html
- http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Category:Emacs_Lisp and so http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to find out the things :)